# Creating a stream of multiple tuples out of one tuple pair

Tags: java, stream

Let's say I have a tuple (1, 2). I want to create a stream, that gives me all possible combinations of that tuples' values.
So I want to create a stream that looks like this:

[(1, 1), (1, 2), (2, 1), (2, 2)]

This is my class for my tupels:

```
public class Tupel<T> {

    private final T first;
    private final T second;

    public Tupel(T first, T second) {
        assert first != null;
        assert second != null;

        this.first = first;
        this.second = second;
    }

    public T getFirst() {
        return first;
    }

    public T getSecond() {
        return second;
    }

    @Override

...
```

This is my class for my tuple pairs:

```
public class TupelPairs<T> {
    private TupleSet<T> tupleSet;

    public TupelPais(TupleSet<T> tupleSet) {
    this.tupelSet = tupleSet;
    //This is where I want to create my tuple pairs
    }

   
    public Stream<Tupel<T>> getElements() {
    return; //This is where I want to return my Stream of those tupel pairs
}
```

How could do I create those tuple pairs?

Comment: What is TupleSet in your class?

Comment: It's the interface I implemented a basic set for all my other sets. I just thought it wouldn't matter to solve my question, since I just want to know how to build that stream

Comment: you gave an example of 2 numbers but set can contain more than 2 values so thats little confusing.

Comment: Yeah you are right, in my task I implement different kind of sets with streams like whole numbers, natural numbers or just a set of numbers. I was just trying to explain what I am trying to accomplish by giving an easy example

Comment: What your tuple set will have tuple of 2 values or values themselves?

Comment: Always tuples of 2 values yes. When I give it a set that contains: [0, 1, 2, 3] I want to get that tuple list: [(0,0),(1,1),(2,2),(3,3),(0,1),(0,2)(0,3),(1,0),(1,2),(1,3),(2,0),(2,1),(2,3),(3,0)(3,1),(3,2)] so 16 tuple values in total.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to produce every pair from your set and easiest way I can think of right now

```
List<T> vals = new ArrayList(tupleSet);
Set<Tuple<T>> set = new HashSet();

for(int i = 0; i < vals.size() - 1; i++) {
  for (int j = i+1; j < vals.size(); j++) {
     set.add(new Tuple(vals.get(i), vals.get(j)));
  }
}
```

Now for each tuple we need to generate permutations of its elements, since you have two elements in tuple only so there would be 4 permutations always.

You can find the algorithm to generate permutations online, you can store each permutation combination in tuple, so your one tuple generated above in for loop will generate 4 tuples

```
[(0,1), (1,2)] //we created this in for loop
```

This will produce using algorithm like this

```
[(0,0),(0,1),(1,1),(1,0),(1,1),(1,2),(2,1),(2,2)]
```

Now having this list, you can easily stream it using stream API function provided for every collection.

**Edit:** Since, here the requirement was to produce all pairs possible with 2 numbers, you didn't need the combinations logic (It was little unclear with question description), you can simply run two loops and produce all the tuples needed, something like this

```
public class TupelPairs<T> {
    private TupleSet<T> tupleSet;
    private final List<Tuple<T>> tuples;

    public TupelPais(TupleSet<T> tupleSet) {
       this.tupelSet = tupleSet;
       
       // Convert your TupleSet<T> to some list here
       // nums here is the List<T>, as I am not sure what is TupleSet here

       tuples = new ArrayList<>();
       // here we are generating tuple pairs
       for(int i = 0; i < nums.size(); i++) {
           for (T num : nums) {
                tuples.add(new Tuple<T>(nums.get(i), num));
           }
       }
    }

   
    public Stream<Tupel<T>> getElements() {
      return tuples.stream();   // Initialized in constructor 
    }
}
```

This would give output if suppose called with (assuming TupleSet some sort of set or list of T and T is Integer for example)

```
TuplePairs<Integer> pairs = new TuplePairs<Integer>(asList(1,2,3));

pairs.getElements(); // -> [(1, 1), (1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 1), (2, 2), (2, 3), (3, 1), (3, 2), (3, 3)]
```

Comment: Thank you for your tip with the permutations. I am sure this is the solution for my task and I looked up many different examples, however I am quite unsure how to execute this for my ``Tuple<T>`` type, could you maybe elaborate a bit more on how to get there?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the sample code that is solving your task:

```
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.EqualsAndHashCode;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.ToString;

import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Set<Tuple<Integer>> tuples = createTuples();

        Set<Integer> allIntegers = tuples.stream()
                .flatMap(integerTuple -> Stream.of(integerTuple.getFirst(), integerTuple.getSecond()))
                .collect(Collectors.toSet());

        List<Tuple> allNumberCombinations = allIntegers.stream()
                .flatMap(firstNumber -> allIntegers.stream().map(secondNumber -> new Tuple<>(firstNumber, secondNumber)))
                .sorted(ascendingComparator())
                .collect(Collectors.toList());

        System.out.println(allNumberCombinations);
    }

    private static Set<Tuple<Integer>> createTuples() {
        return new HashSet<Tuple<Integer>>() {
            {
                add(new Tuple<>(1, 2));
                add(new Tuple<>(3, 2));
            }
        };
    }

    private static Comparator<Tuple<Integer>> ascendingComparator() {
        Comparator<Tuple<Integer>> comparingFirst = Comparator.comparing(Tuple::getFirst);
        Comparator<Tuple<Integer>> comparingSecond = Comparator.comparing(Tuple::getSecond);

        return comparingFirst.thenComparing(comparingSecond);
    }

    @Getter
    @ToString
    @AllArgsConstructor
    @EqualsAndHashCode
    private final static class Tuple<T> {
        private final T first;
        private final T second;
    }
}
```

Result will be:

```
[Main.Tuple(first=1, second=1), Main.Tuple(first=1, second=2), Main.Tuple(first=1, second=3), Main.Tuple(first=2, second=1), Main.Tuple(first=2, second=2), Main.Tuple(first=2, second=3), Main.Tuple(first=3, second=1), Main.Tuple(first=3, second=2), Main.Tuple(first=3, second=3)]
```

Short summary of provided code:

1. create tuples
2. get set of all numbers that were in tuples
3. iterate over those numbers - and for each number iterate over all numbers - to create all possible combinations
4. sort tuples to be in ascending order
5. print them